# change default protocol of Azure EventHub from AMQP to HTTPS

Tags: azure, https, amqp

in my case AMOP protocol is blocked by firewall. I just can work with Azure eventhub with https protocol.

I just find:
.NET    EventHubConnectionOptions.TransportType property with EventHubsTransportType.AmqpTcp or EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets

I do not know, how to change the protocol in receiver of my application.

this is my sample code:

```
static async Task Main()
    {
        // Read from the default consumer group: $Default
        string consumerGroup = EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName;

        // Create a blob container client that the event processor will use 
        storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobStorageConnectionString, blobContainerName);

        // Create an event processor client to process events in the event hub
        processor = new EventProcessorClient(storageClient, consumerGroup, ehubNamespaceConnectionString, eventHubName);
        
        // Register handlers for processing events and handling errors
        processor.ProcessEventAsync += ProcessEventHandler;
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ProcessErrorHandler;

        // Start the processing
        await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

        // Wait for 30 seconds for the events to be processed
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        // Stop the processing
        await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
    }

    static async Task ProcessEventHandler(ProcessEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // Write the body of the event to the console window
        Console.WriteLine("\tReceived event: {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Data.Body.ToArray()));

        // Update checkpoint in the blob storage so that the app receives only new events the next time it's run
        await eventArgs.UpdateCheckpointAsync(eventArgs.CancellationToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit convoluted process.

You would want to use [`EventProcessorClient(BlobContainerClient, String, String, EventProcessorClientOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventprocessorclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_EventHubs_EventProcessorClient__ctor_Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobContainerClient_System_String_System_String_Azure_Messaging_EventHubs_EventProcessorClientOptions_) constructor and then specify [`ConnectionOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubconnectionoptions?view=azure-dotnet) in your client options.

There's a property called [`TransportType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubconnectionoptions.transporttype?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_EventHubs_EventHubConnectionOptions_TransportType) in `ConnectionOptions` which is of type [`EventHubsTransportType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventhubstransporttype?view=azure-dotnet).

You can specify `TransportType` as `EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets` and then you should be able to use AMQP over WebSockets.

Comment: thanks, i did same solution like your suggestion. But  the connection protocol still is AMQP instead of HTTPS

EventProcessorClientOptions cp = new EventProcessorClientOptions();
cp.ConnectionOptions.TransportType = EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
 
// Create an event processor client to process events in the event hub
     processor = new EventProcessorClient(storageClient, consumerGroup, ehubNamespaceConnectionString, eventHubName, cp);

Comment: Can you please elaborate on `But the connection protocol still is AMQP instead of HTTPS`? How are you checking if the protocol is still AMQP and not HTTPS after making this change?